# Constructor is static or non static

Tags: java

As per standard book constructor is a special type of function which is used to initialize  objects.As constructor is defined as a function and inside class function can have only two type either static or non static.My doubt is what constructor is ?

```
1.)As constructor is called without object so it must be static

  Test test =new  Test();//Test() is being called without object
   so must be static
```

My doubt is if constructor is static  method then how can we frequently used this inside 
constructor

```
Test(){
    System.out.println(this);
}
```

Does the output `Test@12aw212` mean constructors are non-static?

Comment: Not completely sure what you're asking, but constructors aren't static in java (though there is a static block).  Constructors setup the object for initial use and are called when instantiated.

Comment: Since when a constructor is static?

Comment: What "standard book"? All the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8) says is that "In all other respects [other than its name], the constructor declaration *looks just like* a method declaration that has no result type" (my emphasis). If your book says anything different from that, it is wrong by definition. There's nothing there that says 'constructors are a special type of function', so the question of static/non-static doesn't even arise. It's not a real question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your second example hits the spot. `this` reference is available in the constructor, which means constructor is executed against some object - the one that is currently being created.

In principle when you create a new object (by using `new` operator), JVM will allocate some memory for it and then call a constructor on that newly created object. Also JVM makes sure that no other method is called before the constructor (that's what makes it special).

Actually, on machine level, constructor is a function with one special, implicit `this` parameter. This special parameter (passed by the runtime) makes the difference between object and static methods. In other words:

```
foo.bar(42);
```

is translated to:

```
bar(foo, 42);
```

where first parameter is named `this`. On the other hand `static` methods are called as-is:

```
Foo.bar(42);
```

translates to:

```
bar(42);
```

`Foo` here is just a namespace existing barely in the source code.

Comment: i got your point but can u please elaborate it means can we say that constructor is non static in nature on its a special which got a special treatment

Comment: @Arun: constructors are normal methods, excepts that: (1) they are not virtual (it wouldn't have much sense) (2) JVM calls them automatically upon `new` operator and (3) you cannot call any method before constructor

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are non-static. Every method first parameter is implicit `this` (except static) and constructor is one of that.

Answer (score 0):

Constructors are NOT static functions. When you do `Test test =new  Test();` a new `Test` object is created and then the constructor is called on that object (I mean `this` points to the newly created object).

Answer (score 0):

The `new` keyword here is the trick. You're correct in noting that in general, if you're calling it without an object, a method is static. However in this special case (i.e., preceded by the `new` keyword) the compiler knows to call the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator returns a reference to the object it created.

```
new Test(); // creates an instance.
```

The `System.out.println(this);` is called after the `new` operator has instantiated the object

Answer (score -1):

Not static. Read about constructors http://www.javaworld.com/jw-10-2000/jw-1013-constructors.html.

Answer (score -1):

Neither.

Methods can be divided into 2 types: static/non-static methods, aka class/instance methods.

But constructors are not methods.

Answer (score -1):

**Static:**

```
Temp t= new Temp();
```

The `new` operator creates memory in the heap area and passes it to the constructor as `Temp(this)` implicitly. It then initializes a non-static instance variable defined in a class called `this` to the local parameter variable `this`.

**Below example is just for understanding the concept, if someone tries to compile it, it will give the compile-time error.**

```
class Temp{
    int a;
    Temp this; //inserted by compiler.
    Temp(Temp this){ //passed by compiler
        this.this=this; // initialise this instance variable here. 
        this.a=10;//when we write only a=10; and all the non-static member access by this implicitly.
        return this; // so that we can't return any value from constructor.
    }
}
```

Constructor is static because:

1. It is helping to create object.
2. It is called without object.

Comment: `this` is not a 'non static instance variable defined in class', and the existence of `this` inside the constructor body proves that you cannot possibly describe it as static.

Comment: It is a pretty strong assertion to say that a constructor is static once it can - and frequently does - initialize instance variables, besides handling the self-reference "this" if necessary. Also, as answered here, the "new" operator creates an instance right before the constructor is called.

Answer (score -1):

When we talk about static class then it comes to our mind that methods are called with class name,But in case of constructor ,Constructor is initialized when object is created So this proves to be non-static.

Answer (score -1):

Constructors are neither static (as called using class name) or non-static as executed while creating an object.

Answer (score -3):

Constructor is used to initialize the object and has the behavior of non-static methods,as non-static methods belong to objects so as constructor also and its invoked by the JVM to initialize the objects with the reference of object,created by new operator