# Are constructors in Java static in nature or non-static in nature?

Tags: java, constructor

There is a similar question 
[Constructor is static or non static](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12940421/constructor-is-static-or-non-static)

But few answers tell that constructor is static and few tell that constructor is non-static. This is confusing. So can anyone please clarify whether constructor is static in nature or non-static in nature?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7780406/why-can-other-methods-be-static-but-a-constructor-cannot ? IMHO, it's best to look at constructors as something special (i.e. not really a method)

Comment: How are you defining static here?

Comment: Static in the sense whether the constructor belongs to the class or the particular instance of the class.

Comment: I'd say it's a little of both. It belongs to the class in the sense that you can call it without yet having a class instance. But it belongs to the instance in the sense that you can reference/call instance members from within the constructor body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure which answer got you confused. But in Java, constructors aren't static.

See the following example:

```
public class MyTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test(); // Prints reference within the constructor
        new Test(); // The reference is different here
    }
}

class Test {
    public Test() {
        System.out.println(this.toString());
    }
}
```

As you can see, by calling constructor twice, you get two different references to the object. This means that context of the constructor is not static.

You may have factory methods in your class, which are static and create instances:

class Test {

```
// May be called like Test.create() and returns instance
public static Test create() {
    return new Test();
}
```

But inside those methods, you'll still have to call class constructor. Which is, as I demonstrated earlier, is not static.

Comment: @Andreas Sorry, isn't having two different references self explanatory?

Comment: You don't have two references, since the code never reaches the second statement. --- Also, I didn't say you were wrong, just that you need to explain.

Comment: So, if you do `Test t = Test.create(); Test t2 = Test.create();`, calling a static method twice to get two references, that makes the create method non-static?

Comment: @Andreas You're right, not sure why I went with exceptions example in the first place. Fixed.

Comment: @JBNizet that would be factory method, and not constructor.

Comment: @AlexeySoshin "by calling constructor twice, you get two different references to the object" do you mean the same object?

Comment: @Saathvik If references are not the same, objects are not the same.

Comment: @JBNizet I think the point of the code wasn't that the returned reference is different, but that `this` inside the constructor is a different reference each time (that's why the print statement is inside the constructor). So to show that your `create` method isn't static, you'd have to show that `this` inside that method refers to a different object each time (which you can't because static methods don't even have access to `this`).

Comment: @sepp2k If the *point* of the answer is that **`this`** inside the constructor is a different reference each time, then the answer should *say* that, and that's all I've been asking for, and why I'm still down-voting it. The answer doesn't say or explain anything about `this`, and neither does JB's comment, so as far as JB's comment is concerned, it highlights the lack of explanation in the answer, i.e. the answer is *unclear*.

Answer (score 4):

This is what Java Specification says about constructors, in [§8.8.3. Constructor Modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.3):

> Unlike methods, a constructor cannot be `abstract`, `static`, `final`, `native`, `strictfp`, or `synchronized`:
>
> - A constructor is not inherited, so there is no need to declare it `final`.
> - An `abstract` constructor could never be implemented.
> - **A constructor is always invoked with respect to an object, so it makes no sense for a constructor to be `static`.**
> - There is no practical need for a constructor to be `synchronized`, because it would lock the object under construction, which is normally not made available to other threads until all constructors for the object have completed their work.
> - The lack of `native` constructors is an arbitrary language design choice that makes it easy for an implementation of the Java Virtual Machine to verify that superclass constructors are always properly invoked during object creation.
> - The inability to declare a constructor as `strictfp` (in contrast to a method ([§8.4.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3))) is an intentional language design choice; it effectively ensures that a constructor is FP-strict if and only if its class is FP-strict ([§15.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4)).